# Some people say you can handle any global(XA) transaction with Spring + hibernate, true or not?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, xa

Some people say you can handle any global transaction with Spring + hibernate, true or not?

Other people say you also need an application server XA datasource or another XA JTA implementation like atomikos or JbossTS or Bitronix.

Which people are correct?
A)spring + hibernate
B)spring + hibernate + another XA JTA implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Neither Spring nor Hibernate comes with an XA-enabled transaction manager. So you indeed need such a transaction manager in order to have distributed transactions with Spring/Hibernate.

This is explained in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction-global).

Comment: Finally a clear answer. I read several articles,but it was still not clear.Thanks for the clear answer.